# Cannot use fracdiff.sim and arfima.sim from python - 'DocumentedSTFunction' object has no attribute 'sim'

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to use R packages `fracdiff` and `arfima` from python. I imported this libraries with `rpy2` as

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
fracdiff = importr('fracdiff')
arfima = importr('arfima')
```

But when I try to execute

```
fracdiff.fracdiff.sim()
```

or

```
arfima.arfima.sim()
```

I received error

> AttributeError: 'DocumentedSTFunction' object has no attribute 'sim'

Both of them are executed in R console. In python only `fracdiff.fracdiff()` and `arfima.arfima()` are executed. What can be wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dots (`.`) are not valid names for Python variables.

For that reason, `importr` is trying to convert `.` into `_`.

Try `fracdiff.fracdiff_sim()`.